# how to uninstall couchdb 1.6.1 version in debian system

Tags: couchdb

I have couchdb 1.6.1 installed on my debian machine. I want to uninstall it.
I tried using **apt-get remove/purge couchdb/couchdb-bin**. This did not help uninstalling couchdb.Is there any other way to uninstall couchdb from debian machine?

Comment: CouchDB does not behave any different than any other package on Debian machines. How do you determine that it doesn’t get uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

The latest [Debian CouchDB package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/couchdb) is 1.4, so you probably installed following the [wiki procedure](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Debian). Looking at the Makefile in the specified tarball, there's an `uninstall`.

Find where you extracted the CouchDB source tarball and run:

```
make uninstall
```

Comment: I used ansible Scripts for installation guillaumededrie.couchdb. I tried it make uninstall, But it's not working.